# How can i handle an empty sql response?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, response

How can i add a handle to this code if the sql response is empty?

```
<?php
$userReferrals_query = sql_query("SELECT id as id2 FROM balances WHERE email = '$address'");
$id2 = fetch_assoc($userReferrals_query); 


$userReferrals_query2 = sql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS referrals FROM balances WHERE referredby = '".$id2['id2']."'");
$referrals = fetch_assoc($userReferrals_query2); 
?>
```

Comment: sql_query is a wrapper for something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
if(empty($id2)){
//Code to handle empty response
}
```

Comment: `is_empty` is not a generic php function.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois thank for that. It's still early here ;) Updated.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch_assoc()` returns `false` if there are no remaining rows in the result. If you're just fetching 1 row, and there's no matching row, it returns `false` on the first call. So just test whether `$id2` is truthy or false:

```
if ($id2) {
    // do referrals query
}
```

Or you could simply combine the two queries with a `JOIN`:

```
$userReferralsQuery = sql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS referrals 
                                 FROM balances AS b1
                                 JOIN balances AS b2 ON b1.referred_by = b2.id
                                 WHERE b2.email = '$address'";
```

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out! :)